Branch and bound algorithm to find the shortest path with constraints
I have a directed graph G with two edge attributes "cost" and "toll" representing different metrics from node i to j.
Now I want to calculate the shortest path (minimum cost) from start to end (constraint toll <= max_toll), but my code's result is different with the python networkx api's (nx.dijkstra_path) result, so is there a possibile logic error in my code? Can someone help or specify the cause of the error?
This is the api code:
min_path = nx.dijkstra_path(G, 0, 49, weight="cost")

This is my code:
def dijkstra_with_toll_constraint(G, start, end, max_toll):
    pq = [(0, start, 0, [start])]  # (sum_cost, current_node, sum_toll, path)
    visited = set()
    while pq:
        cost, node, toll, path = heapq.heappop(pq)
        if node == end and toll <= max_toll:
            return cost, toll, path

        if node in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(node)

        for neighbor in G.neighbors(node):
            next_cost = cost + G[node][neighbor]["cost"]
            next_toll = toll + G[node][neighbor]["toll"]
            if next_toll <= max_toll:
                heapq.heappush(pq, (next_cost, neighbor, next_toll, path + [neighbor]))

    return float("inf"), float("inf"), None


Two things, assuming you have toll values that are positive for some edges on the shortest path:

nx.dijkstra_path is not toll aware, so why would you expect its result to be the same?
If you reach an already visited node with a lower total toll than on any previous visit, you need to 'revisit' it, i.e. you cannot just continue. The cost may be higher then on previous visits, but the lower toll may allow a path to the end node prohibited for continuations of previous paths reaching the node. Your visited should be a dictionary of lowest toll for visits instead of a set.


Do not add “solved” to the title. If sou have a solution, you can post it as an answer.
